# SQL Inner Join issues

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

Currently I have the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM `clients` 
WHERE `ID`=(SELECT `clientID` 
            FROM `websites` 
            WHERE `name` LIKE "%my name%") 
LIMIT 0,20
```

I wish to use an inner join, because AFAIK that is how it should be handled.

I have no idea how to do it... Here is all I could think of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `clients` 
WHERE INNER JOIN `websites` ON `websites`.`name` LIKE "%lead%" 
LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: be careful, if Id in your subquery are repeated could give you different result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT c.* FROM `clients` c
INNER JOIN `websites` w ON w.clientID = c.ID
WHERE w.`name` LIKE '%lead%'
LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this show only results in the clients table?
I tried SELECT clients.* however that errored.